# Firebase android studio not inserting data correctly

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-studio

[This is the data being inserted the the correct one is the yay@gmail.com while the incorrectly inserted ones are the ones with a:Name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/10Xbr.png)

```
  mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, pass)
                    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                            if(task.isSuccessful()) {
                                Teachers teachers = new Teachers(user, pass, email);

                                FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Teachers")
                                        .child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()).setValue(teachers).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {

                                        if(task.isSuccessful()) {
                                            Toast.makeText(RegisterTeacher.this, "Teacher has been registered!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                            Intent i = new Intent(RegisterTeacher.this, TeacherLogin.class);

                                            startActivity(i);
                                        }
                                        else {
                                            Toast.makeText(RegisterTeacher.this, "Failed to register!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        }

                                    }
                                });
                            } else {
                                Toast.makeText(RegisterTeacher.this, "Failed to register! Try again!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }
                    });
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You are doing some funky (bad ideas) stuff there, passing a Teachers object that contains (undoubtedly) plaintext credentials back to Firestore afgter it is created in Firebase Auth - why do you need to store credntials twice like that (hint: you don't). Furthermore you should not rely on the Android app to do such a thing, a Firestore-triggered CloudFunction or CallableFunction would better serve you and the security needs of potential users.

Comment: What does `not inserting data correctly` mean? What exactly isn't inserted correctly?